# How to extract the frequency of raster values from polygons in terra?

Tags: raster, r, extract, terra

I have raster layer of days in which the temperature exceeds the threshold of 0 degrees, and a shapefile of the states of United States.
I would like to extract the frequency of the pixel values per ecoregion in `terra` in R. So far I have tried this:

```
library(terra)

x = rast("D:/temperature/data.tif")
states = vect("D:/studyarea/US_states.shp")
states = project(states, x)
z = extract(x, states, na.rm = T, fun = freq(x))
```

and

```
z = extract(freq(x), states, na.rm = T)
```

But it did not work.
How can I extract the frequency of the raster values per state?

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did it all come back zeroes? Error messages? Are your data correctly spatially referenced? Can you show a map or summary info of your data? We don't have your data so we can't replicate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- round(rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))/100)
names(r) <- "days"
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
```

You can use `crosstab` for this after rasterizing the polygons

```
x <- rasterize(v, r, "NAME_2", wopt=list(names="states"))
ct <- crosstab(c(x, r))
ct
#                  days
#states               1   2   3   4   5
#  Capellen           0   0 260  70   0
#  Clervaux           0   0   3 139 419
#  Diekirch           0  43 195 129  27
#  Echternach         0  35 208  81   0
#  Esch-sur-Alzette   0   8 369  57   0
#  Grevenmacher       3  79 273  24   0
#  Luxembourg         0  14 321  88   0
#  Mersch             0  44 265 111   0
#  Redange            0   0 198 145 123
#  Remich             7 116  95   3   0
#  Vianden            0   7  46  45  32
#  Wiltz              0   0  48 279 146
```

You can create a "long" format data.frame like this

```
b <- as.data.frame(a)
head(b)
#            states days Freq
#1         Capellen    1    0
#2         Clervaux    1    0
#3         Diekirch    1    0
#4       Echternach    1    0
#5 Esch-sur-Alzette    1    0
#6     Grevenmacher    1    3
```

Alternatively, you can use `extract`

```
e <- extract(r, v, table, ID=FALSE)[[1]]
```

`e` is a list in which element matches a geometry in `v`. The table for the first geometry is

```
e[[1]]

  3   4   5 
  3 139 419
```

But the nice thing about aldo_tapia's answer is that you can more easily combine the results for each layer (by calling `do.call(rbind, output)` after the loop. With the above you can get there like this:

```
z <- lapply(1:length(e), \(i) cbind(geom=i, as.data.frame(e[[i]])))
out <- do.call(rbind, z)
out$geom <- v$NAME_2[out$geom]

head(out)
#      geom Var1 Freq
#1 Clervaux    3    3
#2 Clervaux    4  139
#3 Clervaux    5  419
#4 Diekirch    2   43
#5 Diekirch    3  195
#6 Diekirch    4  129
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop for this purpose, saving the results in a list:

```
output <- list()

for(i in seq_along(states)){
  x_temp <- crop(x, states[i,])
  output[[i]] <- freq(x_temp)
}
```

Comment: For this to be correct you need to also mask `x_temp` with `states[i,]`. You can use `crop(x, states[i,], mask=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with `exactextractr`. Although `exactextractr` does not have a `freq` operation, we can get it by multiplying the results of `frac` and `count`.

Using the example data from Robert Hijmans' solution:

```
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)
library(dplyr)

r <- round(rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))/100)
names(r) <- "days"
v <- st_read(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))

exact_extract(r, st_as_sf(v), c('count', 'frac'), append_cols = 'NAME_2') %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('frac'), function(x) x * count))  %>%
    rename_with(function(n) sub('frac', 'freq', n))
```

Result:

```
             NAME_2    count   freq_1     freq_2    freq_3    freq_4    freq_5
1          Clervaux 553.2812 0.000000   0.000000   2.58476 137.85263 412.84379
2          Diekirch 392.1883 0.000000  42.314376 192.78626 128.33565  28.75196
3           Redange 463.6169 0.000000   0.000000 198.47038 143.40036 121.74611
4           Vianden 129.0564 0.000000   6.783227  46.34947  45.16423  30.75945
5             Wiltz 472.7357 0.000000   0.000000  48.08434 276.51430 148.13704
6        Echternach 327.6882 0.000000  35.998649 210.01369  81.67591   0.00000
7            Remich 218.1701 6.276011 114.403333  94.49070   3.00000   0.00000
8      Grevenmacher 373.0518 1.997318  77.842841 270.82947  22.38219   0.00000
9          Capellen 330.4629 0.000000   0.000000 257.97941  72.48348   0.00000
10 Esch-sur-Alzette 432.5632 0.000000   7.804500 367.45097  57.30769   0.00000
11       Luxembourg 424.8329 0.000000  13.882485 321.89943  89.05096   0.00000
12           Mersch 419.2414 0.000000  44.480128 265.39091 109.37033   0.00000
```